# Comparing two files and show the content

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line

I have two files containing content like the following:

```
File 1

OG5_126568
OG5_126583
OG5_126593
OG5_126596
OG5_126599
OG5_126609

File2

OG5_126568  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813339.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_040642027.1
OG5_126583  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_028858051.1
OG5_126585  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt    WP_058023688.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1
```

I want to compare my first file with the second file and produce a new file contains only matched content.

produced file

```
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021813641.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt WP_021814787.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_piscatorii.txt WP_021814787.1
    OG5_126593  psychrobacter_phenylpyruvicus.txt   WP_021814787.1
```

which command should I use?

Comment: You want it to ouput lines from the second file that have matching strings from first file but your expected output doesn't reflect that. If that's what you want then your output should be all of the lines except for the one beginning with `OG5_126585` as that string isn't in the first file. Otherwise, it's important that you clarify why you are expecting that output based on the information that you've provided.

Comment: I am writing a script, which checks each OG5 number of file one and matches it with second file and print all the matching patterns.

Comment: As previously stated, your output doesn't do that. It only prints the matches for `OG5_126593`. Collectively, the strings in the first file first file match every line in the second file except for `OG5_126585`. Your output should be all of the lines except for the one beginning with `OG5_126585`. You aren't being clear which makes it more difficult for anyone to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar to one which already has an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272717/inner-join-on-two-text-files

The simplest way (and working for your example file content) is to use

```
join file1 file2
```

This assumes that the input files are sorted.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, it only prints one element. I mean when OG5 match to one element it shows only that and if some other line match with it it will not show.

 output is only shows one match.

Comment: With your sample data, `join file1 file2` returns 7 lines

Comment: You might need to sort both files.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to the `join` solution, but it doesn't require the input files to be sorted.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {f1[$1]; next} $1 in f1' file{1,2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the lines from File1 as patterns and print all lines that 'match' one of them, you could use `grep`:

```
grep -f File1 File2
```